# Rewriting props passed to static functional component in react

Tags: reactjs

I am currently using the method "table" which is inside a class-component to render several table items (table rows).

The function uses the component "Row" for the table row.

It seems a bit verbose and I wonder if there is the chance to pass properties to the child in a more compact way ?

````
//table is a method inside a class
  public table(data: any[] | ""){
   return (
      <table>
      {data !== "" && data.map((item)=>{ 
      return (<Row 
              name={item.name} 
              x={item.meta.xAxisUnits} 
              y={item.meta.yAxisUnits} 
              memo={item.meta.memo} />
       )}
    </table>
   )
  }

}

function Row(props:any){
  return (<tr>
              <td>props.name</td>
              <td>props.x</td>
              <td>props.y</td>
              <td>props.memo</td>
       </tr>
)}
```
````

Answer (score 0):

You could pass item and let Row figure it out.

```
<Row item={item} />
```

And if you don't want that logic in the Row component you could establish a list of columns that Row just iterates:

```
const columns = [
  item => item.name,
  item => item.meta.xAxisUnits,
  item => item.meta.yAxisUnits,
  item => item.meta.memo,
];

function Row({item}) {
  return (
    <tr>
      { columns.map((c, i) => (
          <td key={i}>{c(item)}</td>
      ))}
    </tr>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could compose your components, like follow:

```js
const Row = (props:any) => (
  <tr>
    <td>props.name</td>
    <td>props.x</td>
    <td>props.y</td>
    <td>props.memo</td>
  </tr>
)

const Table = ({children}) => (
  <table>
    {children}
  </table>
)

Table.Row = Row;

// and then use it like this:

<Table>
  {item.map((i) => <Table.Row {...i} />)}
</Table>
```